# Microsoft Visio - What is the shape name if it exists?

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes

I am trying to depict an x number of servers.

I want to do something like this:

(pic of server 1) (pic of server 2) ... (pic of server n)

What is the standard way to depict the "..." part? I tried making small circles for the dots, but the circles when resized very small disappears!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You did not mention what version of Visio you have. Here is how to do what you are trying in the version I have.

1. Create a standard connector between items.
2. Select then right click the connector you want to be just dots.
3. Choose `Format`, then `Line` from the context menu.

[image]
 4. Changing the line pattern to dots is what you described. Choose the properties you desire and click `OK`.

 
Here is the result.

[image]